# Single values, comma separated values in slicers in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table that contains comma-separated values and single values in a column (text data type).
I do transformations and make a unique list of all single values and comma-separated values. When I click on the slicer and select any value it shows only one single valued row, not including comma-separated value rows.

[image]

Here is my Dataset:

```
Name    Fax     Phone        Email                  Comments
-----   -----   ------       ------                  --------
Ravi    401852  258525       hi                 Email missing
Raju            754569       gsk@protonmail.com fax missing
Reetu   475875                                   Email Missing, Phone Missing
Heera                                            Fax Missing, Phone Missng, Email Missing
naidu                        naidu@company.com   Fax missing, Phone Missing
```

Now I am doing transformation on comments and making a unique list like the below by taking a reference from this dataset.

```
Email Missing
Fax Missing
Phone Missing
```

I am using this unique list in my slicer to filter the data in a table. But it doesn't fulfill my requirement.

It missing the CSV values and display only single values.

Example:
When I select "fax Missing" from the slicer, it shows only

```
Raju            754569       gsk@protonmail.com fax missing
```

But I required all the records including comma-separated ones, i.e. I expected the records of Raju, heera and naidu to display.

Comment: Name Fax Phone Email                 Comments
-----   -----   ------  ------                  --------
Ravi  401852 258525 hi                 Email missing
Raju  754569 gsk@protonmail.com fax missing
Reetu 475875                   Email Missing, Phone Missing
Heera                    Fax Missing, Phone Missng, Email Missing
naidu   naidu@company.com Fax missing, Phone Missing

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following measure to filter the fact using unique values from the slicer.

```
Measure =
VAR _isfiltered =
    ISFILTERED ( Slicer[Slicer.Value] )
VAR _count =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( 'Fact'[Fact.Comments] ),
        FILTER (
            VALUES ( 'Fact'[Fact.Comments] ),
            CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Fact'[Fact.Comments], SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer[Slicer.Value] ) )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _isfiltered == TRUE, _count, 0 )
```

**`_isfiltered`** ensures that **`false`** is returned when nothing is selected.

**`CONTAINSSTRING`** reads through the comma-separated values.

Finally, results are returned as long as there is a selection.

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

Comment: Good work. This solution works but OP should be advised that this is a poor data model and the data should really be reshaped in Power Query in the first instance.